# Do reviewers follow any guidelines about tags in titles?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, rejected-edits, title

As a good citizen, I decided to help the community by removing unnecessary tags included in titles. I try to follow the rules stated in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/159159) and if in doubt, I leave the question as is.

However, I'm a bit confused about some of my edits that got rejected like the one I did about this question: [Write data to xml file? (Visual Studio 2013,c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988113/remove-data-from-xml-file-and-listbox)

I know some of you are still debating about the use of tags when it's part of the question but in this case, the text in the parentheses are clearly tags.  Just to add to my confusion, 1 hour after my edit got rejected, another user made almost the same edit (he also removed 1 line in the text).

My question has 2 parts:

1. Do reviewers follow any guidelines about the tags in title?
2. Should I continue to remove tags from titles or am I generating unnecessary work for the reviewers?

Comment: *Just* removing the tag in the title would have qualified as "too minor" before that reason was canned. Make sure you are fixing *every* error in the post.

Comment: Good point, I'll try to be an even better citizen.  But what if there's no other error in the post?  Is it enough to justify an edit?

Comment: For users who *put* tags in the titles, you'll have a hard time finding one that is true for. That said, yes, its fine to edit that way in such a case., especially once you are over 2K.